# Insert string based on content of current and previous row without helper columns?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have this list for which I want to insert word "NEXT_COUNTRY" before each row containing "NAME" where previous rows is empty/blank.

```
WORLD
COUNT
COUNTRIES

NAME
CAPITAL

NAME
CAPITAL
POPULATION

COUNT
CAPITAL
```

Below is how it looks the input and output column I'm trying to get.

[image: INPUT and OUTPUT]

Is there a way to get this in a single step without creating several helper columns?

I'm trying with `List.Accumulate()` (taking example from [here](https://gorilla.bi/power-query/list-accumulate/)) like below but still don't get desired output.

```
= List.Accumulate(
     Source[DATA],  
     "",          
     ( state, current ) => 
          if state = "" then current else
          Text.Combine( { state } & { Text.From( current ) }, " - " )
)
```

**UPDATE**

Below is the current code but is not working.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WUoCDcP8gHxelWB1kMWf/UL8QJDEwP8jTNRgshqZYwc/R1xVFzNkxwDPE0Yd0xWCBAP+AUB/HEE9/P6XYWAA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [INPUT = _t]),
    ChangeType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"INPUT", type text}}),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(ChangeType,{{"INPUT", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Trimmed Text", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each try if [INPUT] = null and Source[INPUT]{[Index]+1} = "NAME" then "NEXT_COUNTRY" else [INPUT] otherwise [INPUT])
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED ANSWER**

Try

```
let Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WUoCDcP8gHxelWB1kMWf/UL8QJDEwP8jTNRgshqZYwc/R1xVFzNkxwDPE0Yd0xWCBAP+AUB/HEE9/P6XYWAA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [INPUT = _t]),
ChangeType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"INPUT", type text}}),
#"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(ChangeType,{{"INPUT", Text.Trim, type text}}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Trimmed Text", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each if [INPUT]="" and  #"Added Index"{[Index]+1}[INPUT]="NAME" then "NEXT_COUNTRY" else [INPUT])
in  #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, not sure but doesn't insert the string. Additionally, this is a short sample and in actual data there are more blank rows for which I don't want to insert the string, because of that the condition to insert the string only when there is a blank row and next row contains `NAME`. I've updated the input column and output for you to understand better. Thanks

Comment: Edited answer above

Comment: I've added as you suggested and is not working. I've pasted the whole code in my original post below "UPDATE". Thanks

Comment: edited again above

Comment: Excellent, this time it works. I see that your change was in this part `#"Added Index"{[Index] + 1}[INPUT]`

Comment: It would be helpful in the future to include a "Before" view that can be reproduced, and without anyone retyping it